# Iterating through an object array in js: skip when undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I'd like to iterate trough a javascript array (nested objects: based on collection+Json) and collect data from its objects. But if the data of an object isn't available, skip it and go to the next object, resp. continue the iteration. Currently, this error appears if the data isn't available in the according object: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hk5' of undefined`

How can I check first, if the data (hereafter hk5) is available?

**Iterating through all "data-objects"**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.collection.items.length; i++) {
    var data = data.collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data_params.hk5;
    console.log(belaMode);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: By using an [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). `if` statements let you conditional execute code. They look like `if (some condition) { /*do something if true */ } else { /* do something if false */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.collection.items.length; i++) {
    if(typeof(data.collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data_params) != 'undefined'){
    var data = data.collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data_params.hk5;
    }
    console.log(belaMode);
}
```

Comment: You've gone one property too far. The OP wants to test if *application_data_params* is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.collection.items[i].data[2].value.packet_data_field.application_data_params!=undefined){}
```